# How to two runner property include in one test case class?

Tags: junit, parameterized, testng-dataprovider

```
 @RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class DatabaseModelTest {   
   // some tests
     }
```

or

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
       @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
       public class DatabaseModelTest {   
      // some tests
       }
```

- We can not use two runner property  in one test case class...!! so that
- I want to run test case with Multiple data how i pass multiple parameter in Rest web service to execute test case ??
- Any solution for extend class for DataProviderRunner or parameterized ??

Thanks 
(stayconnected52)

Comment: Why not using your own runner which merge the behavior of the two others?

Comment: please give me example i tried like extends class and set runner in super class but it cant get property of that runner @juherr !!
Give me one example what u want to say ? thanks.

Comment: Why do you need two runners? These two runners are different approaches for parameterized tests. Normally you should only need one of them.

Comment: @StefanBirkner edited ..thanks
one for Sprint junit  test class execute and second for data provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Spring's JUnit rules instead of the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. This works at least with the `Parameterized` runner. I don't know whether it works with the `DataProviderRunner`, too.
You need at least version 4.2.0 of the Spring framework and spring-test.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DatabaseModelTest {   
  @ClassRule
  public static final SpringClassRule SCR = new SpringClassRule();

  @Rule
  public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

  ...
}
```

Comment: can u explain how to defind @classrule and got error like
**The at ClassRule 'SCR' must implement MethodRule or TestRule**

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using? You should use JUnit 4.12.

Comment: got solution thanks problem is Spring version answer updated.. in ur answer

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution of @Stefan and works also well for `@RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)`

I found a second solution in [DataProvider for Spring Integration Testing](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks), they wrote a  class [DataProviderRunnerWithSpring](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider/tree/spring-acceptance-test/src/integTest/java/com/tngtech/test/java/junit/dataprovider/spring)  and set the test class like:

```
@RunWith(DataProviderRunnerWithSpring.class)
public class TestClass{ 
... 
}
```